# Best Practices? Converting from pointers to Unique_Ptrs

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am trying to convert from naked pointers to smart pointers.
But I am not quite sure how to keep currentBar (Who will also be located in myBars) while using unique pointers

```
Class Foo
{
  public:
     Bar* getCurrentBar();
     //!! other stuff not important
  private:
     Bar* currentBar;
     std::vector<Bar *> myBars;
  
};
```

I don't believe I should use a shared-pointer as the only thing which has ownership of the object is Foo,

to

```
Class Foo
{
   public:
      std::unique_ptr<Bar> getCurrentBar(); //? returns currentBar, whatever currentBar is;
   private:
      std::unique_ptr<Bar> currentBar; //? What do I do here?
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> myBars;
 };
```

The above doesn't work, but I would like to do something similar to the above. How do I do this? (I would prefer not to use a shared pointer).

Comment: If `Foo` is supposed to own the pointer even after someone has called `getCurrentBar()`, don't return a `unique_ptr`. Make it: `Bar* getCurrentBar() { return currentBar.get(); }`.- Also, you can't have the same pointer wrapped in `unique_ptr` in both `currentBar` and `myBars`.  Btw, do you have to use pointers at all? Why not `std::vector<Bar> myBars;`?

Comment: not the topic of the question, but once you returned a pointer to non-const or a non-const reference from a public getter you don't need to make the member private. By calling `getCurrentBar` the caller has direct access to the member, all access protection is bypassed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with non-owning raw pointers.  Use the `unique_ptr` in the vector to manage the lifetimes, and then use regular pointers or references for your interface.  That would look like

```
Class Foo
{
  public:
     Bar* getCurrentBar(); 
     // or Bar& getCurrentBar();
  private:
     Bar* currentBar;
     std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> myBars;
  
};
```

Comment: A note on why `std::unique_ptr<Bar> getCurrentBar();` is bad: in making the `std::unique_ptr<Bar>` that is returned, the current  holder will be stripped of ownership. Remember that unique means there can be only one. If you pass a `unique_ptr` you are transferring ownership to maintain the uniqueness. If you have somehow have multiple `std::unique_ptr`s  pointing at the same object, you've broken the rules and are in for a rough time.